# grouping algorithm java n choose k

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 10 numbers in a vector container contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. And I want n numbers in a group, for example:

n = 3

[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]
[2,3,4], [5,6,7], [8,9,10], [1]

Is there an algorithm to find all the combinations?

```
    int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};      

    int k = 3;

    List<int[]> subsets = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] s = new int[k];  // here we'll keep indices 
                           // pointing to elements in input array

    if (k <= input.length) {
        // first index sequence: 0, 1, 2, ...
        for (int i = 0; (s[i] = i) < k - 1; i++);  
        subsets.add(getSubset(input, s));
        for(;;) {
            int i;
            // find position of item that can be incremented
            for (i = k - 1; i >= 0 && s[i] == input.length - k + i; i--); 
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
            s[i]++;                    // increment this item
            for (++i; i < k; i++) {    // fill up remaining items
                s[i] = s[i - 1] + 1; 
            }
            subsets.add(getSubset(input, s));
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < subsets.size();i++) {

        int[] result = subsets.get(i);

        for(int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(result[j]+" ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}

int[] getSubset(int[] input, int[] subset) {
    int[] result = new int[subset.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < subset.length; i++) 
        result[i] = input[subset[i]];
    return result;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"Is there an algorithm to find all the combinations?"* Yes, and if you search the web, you'll find one.

Comment: Maybe this thread could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840430/perfoming-cartesian-product-on-arrays

Comment: Do you consider partitions [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10] and [4,5,6], [1,2,3], [7,8,9], [10] equal?

Comment: yes, they are equal